# How to convert user field values into objects for adding permissions in powershell?

Tags: powershell, permissions, role-assignment

I have a list with a multi select (user and group) field. I want to grab the values from there and then pass them to the add permissions method.

I grab the values but they come out like this

```
12;#Hanks, Tom 13;#Portal Visitors
```

How can I convert this into something that can be passed into the `New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment` method so I can add their name to permissions, whether its a user or group?

If I try ensure user on `Hanks, Tom`, won't that be an issue incase there are 2 people called Tom Hanks?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value from a multi-user field is actually a user object. You should be able to do the following to ensure the user from login name and add role assignments:

```
if (!(Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -EA SilentlyContinue)) {
    Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -EA SilentlyContinue
}
# get web
$web = Get-SPWeb http://myintranet
# get role def
$role = $web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"]
# get list
$list = $web.Lists["MyList"]
# get item
$item = $list.GetItemById(1)
# get MultiUser field 'PermUsers' value
$item["PermUsers"] | ForEach-Object {
    # ensure user exists OR get group
    if ($_.User) {
        $user = $web.EnsureUser($_.User.UserLogin)
    } else {
        $user = $web.SiteGroups[$_.LookupValue]
    }
    # add assignment for user
    $assignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($user)
    # add role for assignment
    $assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($role)
    # add assignment to list
    $list.RoleAssignments.Add($assignment)
}
# update list
$list.Update()
# dispose web
$web.Dispose()
```

Hope this helps!

Updated to work with both Users and SharePoint Groups.

Comment: Does this work with groups too?

Comment: It does now, I've added a check to see if the User property exists, and set user variable to either User or Group accordingly.